# Node js: How to get file signature headers instead of mime-type?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, mime-types, file-extension

I downloaded [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types) module for my node js project, and it seems to work fine up to a certain point. If you `console.log(mime.lookup(pathToFile));` it returns the correct file type that the file has. The problem is that it checks the file extension to get the file type and not check the first couple of bytes of the file (file signature headers) to actually get the correct file type. So if I have a `.png` image, it returns `image/png` but if I just were to change the file extension to something like `.mp4` it thinks that the file is a `video/mp4`. Is there a way to check it safely so that some user doesn't just upload something harmful to the server? Maybe another module? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type).

> Detect the file type of a Buffer/Uint8Array
>
> The file type is detected by checking the magic number of the buffer.

```
const readChunk = require('read-chunk'); // npm install read-chunk 
const fileType = require('file-type');
const buffer = readChunk.sync('unicorn.png', 0, 262);

fileType(buffer);
//=> {ext: 'png', mime: 'image/png'}
```

It requires to read the first 262 bytes. Check the supported extensions on the [page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type#supported-file-types)

Comment: On line 3 what does 0 and 262 stand for?

Comment: start from 0th position, read 262 bytes, read the first 262 bytes

Comment: Also, is there a way to check it before the file get's uploaded? Thank you!

Comment: you should check the client side example here https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type#browser

Comment: you should give proper reference to the file, remove the . in the beginning and check. also are you storing the file without validating its type?