# Query Regarding File Upload

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I am using  "File Upload" control and C# coding (backend) for uploading files(.jpeg/.png/.pdf) in my web application.
The files uploaded through this control should be saved in the server.
Everything is working fine but the problem i am facing is when a file type of xlsx or doc is been saved and the extension of that file is changed to .png or .jpeg and is being uploaded it is being uploaded into the server without any error.

While I am trying to open that image or pdf file in server it is as usually showing the error message the file cant be opened.

I have done extension validation but it does not show any effect here in this case.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this problem.(Either C# coding or Jquery Or javascript will do)

Comment: Please add some code which you have tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910291/node-js-how-to-get-file-signature-headers-instead-of-mime-type ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php ... and so on... just to get an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how finally able to get the validation as I need using "Header codes":

```
 System.IO.BinaryReader r = new System.IO.BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);
                                string fileclass = "";
                                byte buffer;
                                try
                                {
                                    buffer = r.ReadByte();
                                    fileclass = buffer.ToString();
                                    buffer = r.ReadByte();
                                    fileclass += buffer.ToString();
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                }
                                r.Close();
                                if (fileclass != "3780" || fileclass != "255216" || fileclass != "13780")    /*Header codes (3780-PDF);(255216-JPG,JPEG);(13780-PNG)*/
                                  {
                                    /*Your code goes here(things to do with the file uploaded)*/
                                  }
```

For getting values for other file formats try uploading the file and set break point and get the header code.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, Updated

> But my problem is the extension is a proper one which i need to upload
>   but the file type is not i mean an excel sheet can be saved with
>   extension jpeg

You can use `FileReader`, `.readAsBinaryString()` to check for file headers; e.g, `JFIF` for `.jpeg`, `.jpg`; `PNG` for `.png`; `PDF` for `.pdf`; `RegExp.prototype.test()` with `RegExp` `/JFIF|PNG|PDF/`

---

Use `accept` attribute at `<input type="file">` element with value set to `".jpeg,.jpg, .png,.pdf"` to exclude files with extensions other than `.jpeg`, `.jpg`, `.png` or `.pdf` from being able to be selected by user at `Choose File` dialog.

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=file]")
  .addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.files[0].type);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event) {
      console.log(event.target.result
                  , /JFIF|PNG|PDF/.test(event.target.result))
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(e.target.files[0])
  })
```

```html
<input type="file" accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.pdf" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the response
I got it what u r saying 
But my problem is the extension is a proper one which i need to upload but the file type is not
i mean an excel sheet can be saved with extension jpeg
But u cannot open it using any image viewer or paint
The same file is being uploaded even if we use this type of validation

Comment: @BhanuPrakash You can use `FileReader`, `.readAsBinaryString` to check file headers, see updated post.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us how your validation looks like ?!
There is two way to check the extension of a file that you are uploading. It should be like this following :

```
//In your aspx file :
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" id="Btn_Upload" text="Upload" onclick="Btn_Upload_Click" />

//In your aspx.cs file :
// First soluce
protected void Btn_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType != "application/pdf")
     {
          //Not an PDF
     }
}

// Second soluce :
protected void Btn_Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUploadControl.PostedFile.FileName);
     if (extension != ".pdf")
     {
          //Not an PDF
     }
 }
```

Of course, on these code sample you can add for exception for JPEG / PNG / ...

Comment: I have used the second type of validation .
But the problem here is the extension will be .pdf or .jpeg only but the content is of another type like excel
So it is not validating as extension is proper..

Answer (score 0):

There are many image format, like webp for example why not support them all?
You can convert them client side before you upload them using canvas...

```
function convertImage(image, mimetype, quality) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve){
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.width = image.width
    canvas.height = image.height
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(image, 0, 0)
    canvas.toBlob(resolve, mimetype, quality)
  })
}

if(input.files[0].type === 'application/pdf') {
  // upload directly (not a image)
} else {
  var img = new Image
  img.onerror = function() { /* not an image */}
  img.onload = function() {
    convertImage(img, 'image/png', 1).then(function(blob){
      // upload the converted image
      fetch('upload', {method: 'POST', body: blob})
    })
  }
  img.src = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0])
}
```

then you use this to help filter out the accepted files you want

```
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf, image/*">
```